# C# Regex extract value between string multiple occurrences

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this

> #-cmd1-# Hakona Matata #-cmd2-#

I want to get all values that is like this  #-TEXT-#

Here's the code I use, but it works only when there's one occurrence

```
var text = "#-adsfree-# hakona matata #-adsbottom-#";

Regex regex = new Regex("#-(.*)-#");
var v = regex.Match(text);
string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: You are only doing a single match. Use [Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches).

Comment: The only answer is to exclude the pound sign.  

`\#-([^#]*)-\#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might be designing an expression, maybe similar to:

```
(?<=#-)\b(\w+)\b(?=-#)
```

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=#-)\b(\w+)\b(?=-#)";
        string input = @"#-adsfree-# hakona matata #-adsbottom-#";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sef4nP/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Comment: Can we get the original value in the regex match as well (#-TEXT-#) ?